# Meteor package accounts-facebook doesn't work anymore

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have configured a Facebook login button using `accounts-facebook` package a while ago and it was working fine, but suddenly it's broken (its not working on the localhost as well as on the droplet [giggorilla.co.uk](http://www.giggorilla.co.uk/) ). I searched for the problem and as recommended I updated form meteor version 1.3 to 1.4, same for `accounts-facebook` I upgraded to 1.0.11. I double checked app id and secret key and the Facebook app is currently live and available to the public; however I am using http protocol on the environment server and on live server. This is the problem that I am facing:

> Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook. failed [400] {"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HBMaCroDzQN"}}

packages:

> accounts-ui@1.1.9
>
> accounts-facebook@1.0.11
>
> accounts-twitter@1.1.12
>
> accounts-password@1.3.1

the facebook app config [image]

the social services config [image]

mup config [image]

Comment: Just try one more step...create a new mini app, just for testing, add the facebook package to the app, write the config file with the rights parameters and see if it works there...

Comment: @Hackerman i created a new mini app, and it worked fine!

Comment: Now check if you have any package conflict between the mini app and you app...also the packages version, check if you have any different between them.

Comment: @Hackerman thanks for your help, i've took the hard way to learn it. **FB deprecated an older version of their OAuth API** (which was using with meteor 1.3). The mini app was working with Meteor to 1.4.1 that's way i didn't had a prolem. [https://forums.meteor.com/t/facebook-login-suddenly-broken/35209] ( facebook-accounts-patched)

Comment: Glad to help...some times when you have this kind of issues, an approach like this one, gives you a better insight and understanding.